# What is the time frame used to collect data for oid 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10(ifInOctets(10) )

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

When I do an snmpwalk for oid 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.1 I get a Counter32 integer value as the result. [1] states that 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10 gives total number of octets received on the interface, including framing characters.

Does anybody knows for which time frame snmp gives this integer value because what I get is a pretty large value.

[1] http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10

Thank you.

Comment: Since the last reset of the device - most likely

Answer (score 1):

In RFC 202 you can find the mapping of MIB objects to their corresponding item in IEEE 802.12,

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2020#page-12

That means, SNMP only exposes those values directly from the network adapters, without any processing at SNMP layer. Thus, when you see a value for `ifInOctets`, it is very likely to be an accumulated value since the last reset of this adapter (may or may not be related to device reset).

Comment: Hi Lex, Thanx for the reply.In my graph for network traffic I get values which go up and down. If its giving an accumulated value how this is possible?

Comment: The graph you look might show a timely delta instead of this accumulated value, in order to demonstrate the incoming packet rate. That can have ups and downs. Of course, I don't know which graph you are referring to, so make sure you check carefully what kind of data it shows.

Comment: Hi Lex, I analyzed the data given from oid 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.1 and it gave me these values which go up and down, but 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.1 should give an accumulated value right?

Comment: More info about this device is required to better understand the situation. The RFC documents, as well as my personal experience, show this value should be accumulated. But the vendor of the device (especially the network adapter vendor) might think differently.